# How to delete the first term of a group of strings

Tags: python

I was trying to write a code only to output the days and months from a log file. But there is a header in the first line. How can I get rid of it?

```
with open('running.log','r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in lines:
        
        fields = line[:-1].split('\t')
        
        date = fields[0].split('-')
        time = fields[1]
        temp = fields[2]
        record = (date, time, temp)
        
        
        data.append(record)
        
        days = date[0]
        months = date[-1]
        print(days)
```

my output results are:

```
DATE
7
8
9
10
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
20
22
24
25
26
27
28
```

So how can I get rid of the DATE in the first line?

Comment: Or in your case that you have `lines = file.readlines()`, why not just do `for line in lines[1:]:`?

Comment: Actually looking better at your code, this is basically an XY problem - what you really should be doing is use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) modules, and not read a tabulated file as a regular text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the first line.
Replace

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

by

```
lines = file.readlines()[1:]
```

Note, that readlines(), read the whole file into memory. This might cause a problem if your file is rather big. A way around this is by reading the file line by line. E.g.

```
with open('running.log','r') as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        # do your stuff
```